# Amazon IAP V1 not working on unity

Tags: unity, c#

I've been following the tutorial for amazon iap v1 (because it seems a lot easier than amazon iap v2) but when I built the android app and went onto the shop screen the app just force closed. Here's all the code:
For CurrencyAmount.cs:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using AmazonCommon;

    public class CurrencyAmount : MonoBehaviour {

        public Text coinText;
        public Text diamondText;
        public int coins;
        public int gems;
        public string[] items;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start(){
            AmazonIAP.initiateItemDataRequest(items);
        }
        void Update () {
            coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CoinAmount");
            gems = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("DiamondAmount");
            coinText.text = coins.ToString ();
            diamondText.text = gems.ToString ();

        }
        void itemDataRequestFailedEvent()
        {
            // If you get this response, either retry or stop purchase attempt.
            Debug.Log( "itemDataRequestFailedEvent" );
        }
        void itemDataRequestFinishedEvent( List<string> unavailableSkus, List<AmazonItem> availableItems )
        {
            // Do not continue with the purchase attempt if the your SKU is in the list of unavailable SKUs!
            Debug.Log( "itemDataRequestFinishedEvent. unavailable skus: " + unavailableSkus.Count + ", avaiable items: " + availableItems.Count );
        }

        void purchaseFailedEvent( string reason )
        {
            // The reasons for failure on a Consumable are:
            // INVALID_SKU
            // FAILED
            // You should log the reason, but in every case, do not entitle content
            Debug.Log( "purchaseFailedEvent: " + reason );
        }
        //This is connected to the buttons
        public void BuyGems(string nameOfPackage){
            AmazonIAP.initiatePurchaseRequest( nameOfPackage );
        }


        void purchaseSuccessfulEvent( AmazonReceipt receipt, int GemsToBuy )
        {
            // On successful purchase, you may entitle content
            Debug.Log( "purchaseSuccessfulEvent: " + receipt );

            // You should preserve the token for use with
            // Receipt Verification
            string purchaseToken = receipt.token;
            gems = gems + GemsToBuy;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("DiamondAmount", gems);
            PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        }

    }
```

here's the link for [amazon sdk](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk)

Comment: Try interacting with ADB to find the more precise error. Using mac, run terminal -> goto platform-tools folder of the sdk and run this command: `./adb logcat -s Unity`

Comment: Doesn't matter now @NeverHopeless , I was having so much trouble with amazon that I decided to use google play